# MS Access 2003 - ordering the string values for a listbox not alphabetical

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, ms-access-2003

Here is a silly question. Lets say I have a query that produces for a list box, and it produces values for three stores

```
Store A     18
Store B     32
Store C     54
```

Now if I ORDER BY in the sql statement the only thing it will do is descending or ascending alphabetically but I want a certain order (only because THEY WANT A CERTAIN ORDER) .....so is there a way for me to add something to the SQL to get

```
Store B
Store C
Store A
```

i.e. basically row by row what i want. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a numeric field, *sequencer*, to the table which contains the store names.  Use the *sequencer* values to determine your sort order.

```sql
SELECT sequencer, store_name FROM YourTable ORDER BY sequencer;
```

In the list box, set the column width = 0 for the *sequencer* column.

Or simply, as [@dscarr suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548273/ms-access-2003-ordering-the-string-values-for-a-listbox-not-alphabetical/2548317?noredirect=1#comment52993750_2548317), don't include *sequencer* in the `SELECT` field list, but just include it in the `ORDER BY` ...

```sql
SELECT store_name FROM YourTable ORDER BY sequencer;
```

Comment: this one I had a hunch.....wasn't sure if you can add something to sql to accomplish like the month concept in crosstab. thanks Hans!

Comment: You could add a Switch function to your SQL as astander suggested.  However that approach can be challenging if your query returns more than a few rows.  I would just rather change a value in the sequencer field as needed rather than revising a Switch function.  If you make the sequencer float data type you can assign fractional values to fit new rows into an existing sequence.

Comment: ...Dude honestly that solves what I needed perfectly.....once again (probably for the hundredth time on this website) thanks very much Hans!

Comment: This is definitely the way I would handle it. Adding the switch statement would return potentially inaccurate results if data were added to or removed from the table. Also, you don't need to set the sequencer column's width to 0, simply don't include it in the SELECT clause like this: SELECT store_name FROM YourTable ORDER BY sequencer;  You can still use the sequencer column in the ORDER BY clause even thought it's not being selected.

Comment: @dscarr  That seems so obvious now that you said it.  :-)  I revised the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do 1 of 2 things.

Either use a [SWITCH](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/switch.php) stament, something like

```
SELECT Table1.Store, 
       Table1.Val, 
       Switch([Store]="StoreB",1,[Store]="StoreC",2,[Store]="StoreA",3) AS Expr1
FROM Table1
ORDER BY Switch([Store]="StoreB",1,[Store]="StoreC",2,[Store]="StoreA",3);
```

Or use a secondary order table, that stores the values of the store names, and an order by value.

Comment: I was not at all familiar with that switch statement approach. thanks very much! learned something very cool today!